# Opencart v2.3.0.2 losing cart variables when logging in to user profile

Tags: php, mysql, opencart

I have a very customised OC v2.3.0.2 which adds a single product, when selected and then bypasses the cart directly to checkout. At this stage the product is loaded in the cart, until the checkout forces a login to the user profile to complete the checkout.
After login, the cart has been emptied and I am trying to find out why this happens. It is almost like the session has ended? 
I haven't added any sample code as I am merely asking for an idea as to where I should be looking for a solution. 
Although customised, I am still using the OC framework principles.

Comment: please upload proper screenshot

Comment: Screenshot of what?

Comment: empty cart photo upload

Comment: otherwise send your project url